# WPF datagrid - allow invalid URI

Tags: c#, wpf, hyperlink, datagrid

SOLVED, solution below.

I have a Datagrid in my WPF application. There are some columns with hyperlinks. Here's the desired functionality:

- The link text in the grid can be anything: it can also contain invalid uri.
- When link is clicked, a browser window is opened and user is directed to uri. In case of invalid uri, it just opens a blank window.

Problem: If the link type in Model class is Uri, it can't be constructed with any string because invalid Uri throws an exception. If the link is string, a DataGridTextColumn must be used, and it doesn't have proper formatting and event handlers.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

EDIT: Managed to get it to work. The data in my Model is a string, I use DataGridHyperlinkColumn, and in the click handler I do

```
Debug.WriteLine(((Hyperlink)e.Source).NavigateUri);
```

I think I already tried that before, but obviously not...

Comment: You have two choices, leave it as a URI (Preferred) or change it to a string.  Either way all applications should have user input validation.  Our good friend Magnus has an article here: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/

Comment: The data actually is not modified through the datagrid, but it comes from a database. Of course, I could add input validation. However, I want to allow any string to be stored to the database. The link just won't lead anywhere if it's formatted incorrectly, but it should be displayed in the ui. Anyway, I believe that browsers even tolerate invalid urls to some extent.